# std::construct_at on top of existing object skipping re-initialization of some fields

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

In the following program, in a constant expression, a temporary object of `A` is created with all fields initialized, and then function `f` creates another object of `A` at the same address, skipping (re)initialization of the field `x`, which is read afterwards:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int x;
    constexpr A() {}
    constexpr A(int xx) : x(xx) {}
};

constexpr int f(A && a) { 
    std::construct_at<A>(&a);
    return a.x; 
}

static_assert( f(A{5}) == 5 ); //ok in GCC only
```

GCC accepts it just fine. But other compilers complain, e.g. Clang:

```
note: read of uninitialized object is not allowed in a constant expression
    return a.x; 
           ^
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/87zrEb7q7

Indeed `x` is not initialized in `std::construct_at<A>(&a)`, but it was initialized in `A{5}`.

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: I think Clang is right. Removing ```std::construct_at<A>(&a)``` makes code work in Clang. ```std::construct_at<A>(&a)``` invokes default constructor to construct at the same address, which left ```a.x``` uninitialized.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#direct-object-creation is designed to preserve the object representation for a new object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm convinced this is UB, and GCC is wrong.

`std::construct_at<A>(&a)` creates a new `A` object, and thus a new `int x` member in it. That new object isn't initialized.

For this to be legal, there would have to be a special rule that uninitialized objects may get values based on the contents of memory they occupy, and I don't think such rule exists. [`[basic.indet]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.indet)  doesn't mention it.

Comment: The wording of [basic.indet] on when an indeterminate value is produced is a bit weird though, see e.g. [CWG 1997](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1997).

Comment: Also, constructing `A` on top of existing `A` isn't particularly legal action. Destruction should've been called first, or since it is trivial there is no need?

Comment: @ALX23z It's [legal](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#5) in this case. *"any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior"*

Comment: @user17732522 see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/5213#issuecomment-1018435403 though

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Makes sense to me although it could be made clearer. I suppose that the issue still being active means that it is not that obvious to everyone?

Comment: @user17732522 _I suppose that the issue still being active means that it is not that obvious to everyone?_ I think it means there are more important issues and very few time for them

Comment: @user17732522 and my comment was more about where the (non-)problem is when «no new storage is being obtained», rather than how the issue should be closed

Comment: _I'm convinced this is UB, and GCC is wrong_ If it is UB, then NDR and GCC is not wrong.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I thought there was a requirement to diagnose any UB caused by `constexpr` evaluation? Can't quickly find the revelant quote though.

Comment: [If a function can't ever be used in a core constant expression, the program is IFNDR](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#6.sentence-1). [There are no requirements for IFNDR programs](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.compliance.general#2.3).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Since OP actually calls the function, the program is additionally ill-formed. Yeah, I get your point that due to a different IFNDR, this IF formally might not be diagnosed, but I argue that this is not the intended reading. In practice the compiler is either going to diagnose the IFNDR part, or fail to see it and then diagnose the IF part.

Comment: If you modify the program [like this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EYGPv4saP), it becomes just IF, so GCC is bugged one way or another.

Comment: _Since OP actually calls the function, the program is additionally ill-formed_ It could be ill-formed if it were violating some requirements, but there are none. _If you modify the program like this, it becomes just IF, so GCC is bugged one way or another._ I know, just being pedantic.