# Constant evaluation of self-assignment in member initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, constexpr

In the following program, `constexpr` function `foo()` makes an object of `A` with the field `x=1`, then constructs another object on top of it using `std::construct_at` and default initialization `x=x`, then the constant evaluated value is printed:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x = x;
};

constexpr int foo() {
    A a{1};
    std::construct_at<A>(&a);
    return a.x;
}

constexpr int v = foo();

int main() {
    std::cout << v;
}
```

GCC prints `1` here. Both Clang and MSVC print `0`. And only Clang issues a warning: `field 'x' is uninitialized when used`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WTsxdrj8e

Is there an undefined behavior in the program? If yes, why does no compiler detect it during constant evaluation? If no, which compiler is right?

Comment: You do (direct) [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) of an aggregate (leading to [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)), and that will [copy initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) the member `x`. So the default initialization should not happen. It seems GCC is correct and the others wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there is `std::construct_at<A>(&a);` right after what you described which is UB. @OP compilers aren't almighty and the UB here is hidden under `construct_at`. There was another one recently on SO where compilers would not say anything on `construct_at` on a constexpr object in a constexpr function.

Comment: What is the reason to believe this differs from https://stackoverflow.com/q/70820127/7325599 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104192 . It still looks to involve lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an indeterminate value (now in the initialization instead of in the return), and the other SO answer would imply this is IFNDR. Therefore it doesn't need to be diagnosed.

Comment: In the other question, Clang and MSVC reject the program with `expression did not evaluate to a constant` error, and here all compilers accept the code, although producing distinct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++20 [basic.life]/1.5 states that the lifetime of an object (in this case, the object `a`) ends when

> the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within `o` (6.7.2).

The standard isn't totally clear about when exactly the memory is considered "reused" (and thus, the old `A`'s lifetime ends) but [intro.object]/1 states that

> ... An object occupies a region of storage in its period of construction (11.10.5), throughout its lifetime (6.7.3), and in its period of destruction (11.10.5).

In my opinion, the evaluation of the default member initializer `= x` is something that happens during the "period of construction" of the new `A` object, and that means that at that point, the new `A` object has already come into existence (but its lifetime has not yet begun), and the old object's lifetime has already ended. That means the initialization of the new `A` reads the value of its `x` member, whose lifetime has not begun because its initialization is not complete, which violates [basic.life]/7.1 and would be UB.

In C++20, the definition of `foo` violates [dcl.constexpr]/6:

> A constexpr function that is neither defaulted nor a template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if it is not possible for an evaluation of an invocation of the function to be performed while evaluating any valid manifestly constant-evaluated expression.

This means compilers are not required to issue a diagnostic for your program.

In C++23, this rule will be abolished (see [P2448](https://wg21.link/P2448)) so you can argue that compilers must issue a diagnostic if they claim C++23 compliance. However, no compiler has ever been able to diagnose all kinds of core language UB in constant expressions (for example, something that seems particularly difficult to diagnose is unsequenced writes or an unsequenced read and write involving the same scalar object) so don't hold your breath for it to be fixed.